# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.text.normalizer.NormalizerImpl

Tags: java, java-8, wildfly, noclassdeffounderror

I got the following error on my wildfly 13 server running with oracle jdk 1.8.0_221 (64Bit). The NormalizerImpl is a class from the rt.jar which should be always available. So this is no ordinary ClassNotFound.

```
> 2019-07-25 13:56:38,914 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-20)
> UT005023: Exception handling request to
> /myServletPath:
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
> sun.text.normalizer.NormalizerImpl    at
> java.text.RBTableBuilder.build(RBTableBuilder.java:107)   at
> java.text.RBCollationTables.<init>(RBCollationTables.java:83)     at
> java.text.RuleBasedCollator.<init>(RuleBasedCollator.java:300)    at
> java.text.RuleBasedCollator.<init>(RuleBasedCollator.java:281)    at
> sun.util.locale.provider.CollatorProviderImpl.getInstance(CollatorProviderImpl.java:106)
>   at java.text.Collator.getInstance(Collator.java:242)
```

or a similar one

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.text.normalizer.NormalizerImpl
    at sun.text.normalizer.NormalizerBase.isNormalized(NormalizerBase.java:1671)
    at sun.text.normalizer.NormalizerBase.isNormalized(NormalizerBase.java:1652)
    at java.text.Normalizer.isNormalized(Normalizer.java:177)
```

I googled it but did not found much and strangely nothing on SO ;-)

Answer (score 2):

One hint I just [found](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/360303/why-does-rdz-fail-with-error-javalangnoclassdeffou/) was

(1)

> The error happens when the JVM jar file resources.jar can not be
>   opened causing a failure during initialization of class
>   sun.text.normalizer.NormalizerImpl and thus raises a
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. The problem is most probably an incorrect
>   permission on the JVM directories for the connected user. It can
>   be solved by giving read access to group and others: drwxr-xr-x.

(2) Or they did a restart...